# How to make a temporary cache in HTML 5

Tags: javascript, caching, browser-cache, html5-appcache

I'm looking to make a temporary cache in HTML5, I want to cache my website only for 5 or 6 minutes, and then the cache will be deleted automatically from the user's browser ? using of course Application cache.

Is that possible, if not what's the better way to give an offline version to users, an offline version that can be updated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by HTML5 with Cache Manifest

I hope this will help you --> http://www.sitepoint.com/offline-web-application-tutorial/

try this - http://labs.ft.com/2012/08/basic-offline-html5-web-app/

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not what I'm looking for